# jasper Report - sub report with desire output look like table

Tags: java, jasper-reports

[image]

I want design as above in detail band.. I tried lot but i could not find any proper way to design.
I made 9 sub report's for different content and this design is one of the content's from sub report,in which I tried with table but i dont know how to maintain sub-data-set.

Answer (score 1):

First i have to say, that i don't usually use jasper's table component (too much tricky). The way i deal with sub-reports and displaying them with a table fashion is by adding a line with static fields in the Column Header band (or Group Header, in case you are using jasper groups) and directly below them, in the detail band, all the fields on a single line as well. Then, i set the band height based on the fields height (watch out to have all the fields with the same height, and stretch them if needed)
Sample:
[image]

And the result is:
[image]